# How to compare two dataset with complex value if they are different or not in spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have two datasets (baseline and dataset) in this Structure:

```
public static final StructType SCHEMA =  new StructType()
.add(KEY, StringType, false)
.add(DATASETS, createMapType(StringType, createArrayType(StringType)), true);

// Find rows (just same keys) in newDataset (dataset) that are in oldDataset(baseline) but with different values
Dataset<Row> joined = dataset
.join(baselineData, dataset.col(KEY).equalTo(baselineData.col(KEY)), "inner")
.withColumn("datasets_baseline", baselineData.col(DATASETS))
.withColumn("datasets_new", dataset.col(DATASETS))
.drop(baselineData.col(DATASETS))
.drop(dataset.col(DATASETS));
```

I couldn't do datasets_baseline.notEqualTo(datasets_new) because it is a map type.

Is there any other option to get what I am looking for ?

Tried this :

```
Dataset<Row> newRows = joined     
.select(col(KEY), 
expr("arrays_zip(datasets_baseline, datasets_new) as datasets_diff"))     
.filter(expr("exists(transform(datasets_diff, x -> exists(transform(x, y -> y._1 != y._2))), element -> element)")
.join(dataset, dataset.col(KEY).equalTo(joined.col(KEY)), "inner")
.select(dataset.col(KEY), dataset.col(DATASETS));
```

but different values implies different in order inside the list (map's value) so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: So basically you want a way to compare 2 Columns with Map type?

Comment: Yes @HoangMinhQuangFX15045